# How to use facebook access_token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I´m building a facebook app with php,
everything works perfect, I do successful dialog auth
I have the short_live token
I generate the long_live_token and save it to some directory

what I want to do is that in canvas app the user selects some stuff and activates a mechanism that regularly posts stuff, this is why I save the token.

but what can I do with it?!

I find a lot about generating the access_token but nothing about how to use it!?
Where can I add it as parameter? What is the key?

example:

I´m using facebook sdk for php for post sth. to a wall like

```
$msg_body = array(
    'message' => "wassup yo"
);
$facebook->api($uri, 'post', $msg_body );
```

but this only works if

```
  $facebook->getUser();
```

is returning a user

how can I use my stored access_token to do the same?

Comment: you do know that you are not allowed to prefill the message parameter, right? it always has to be 100% user generated. also, "regular posting" sounds very spammy, the user should be able to authorize every single post - and he has to enter his own message for each one of them.

Comment: @luschn i know that, but i have to start somewhere right ? What i want to achieve is following: the user accepts the permission of the app, chooses a rss-feed of reviews of him from our website and in background i will check if there are new entrys and if so i post it on his wall

Comment: so the whole logic for making a command thats trigerred by cron and checking rss for new entrys is no problem, i just dont know how to use the token to make graph calls, thanks for any help

Comment: alright, i answered, i hope it helps. just comment in the answer if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a function called "setAccessToken" in the Facebook PHP SDK. You would just need to set it with that function and it gets added to every call automatically.

Manual way:

```
$params = array(
    'message' => 'wassup yo',
    'access_token' => '[your-token]'
);
$facebook->api($uri, 'post', $params);
```

You could also do this with CURL, this would be an example URL;

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $userId .
    '/feed' .
    '&access_token=' . $accessToken .
    '&message=' . $userMessage;
```

Basically you just add the Access Token as a parameter like the message.

Just make sure you are using secure calls, see this article for an example of using CURL with the Facebook API and usage of "appsecrect_proof": http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

IMPORTANT: Be sure that the message parameter is always 100% user generated without any prefilling (see Platform Policy) and keep in mind that you need to go through a review process with `pulish_actions` to make it available for other Users: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: thank you very much, i´m using the appsecret_proof and it works like a charme!